# How to type in textbox using Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]
I am using **Selenium 2**.
But after running following code, i could not able to type in textbox.

> ```
>     package Actor;
> import org.openqa.*;
> import org.openqa.selenium.By;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
> import org.junit.*;
> import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
> //import org.junit.Before;
> public class Actor {
>   public Selenium selenium;
>   public WebDriver driver;
>
>   @Before
>   public void setup() throws Exception{
>   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
>       driver.get("http://www.fb.com");
>   }
>   @Test
>   public void Test() throws Exception{
>       //selenium.type("id=gs_htif0", "test");
>       System.out.println("hi");
>       // driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gb_1 > span.gbts")).click();
>           selenium.waitForPageToLoad("300000000");
>
>           WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
>
>           email.sendKeys("nshakuntalas@gmail.com");
>           driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).click();
>   }
>   @After
>   public void Close() throws Exception{
>       System.out.println("how are you?");
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: What goes wrong? Does it throw an exception - if so what, and from which line?

Comment: yes it's throwing java.lang.NullPointerException, and i could not see any thing happening in webdriver's firefox browser

Comment: Can you paste the full error info into your question?

Comment: Why are you mixing up Selenium-RC with Selenium WebDriver? I'd go WebDriver full way.

Comment: Since your edit, you "selenium" variable isn't started, that could pull of a NullPointerException, also you don't need it, since WebDriver waits for the page to load before doing any action.

Comment: @Naveen Chhaniwal: It's better to paste the code precisely. As your problem is typing in textbox, the specific code for that textbox is enough. And it's also better to mention the error details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks Friend, i got an answer. This is only possible because of your help. you all give me a ray of hope towards resolving this problem.

Here is the code:

```java
package facebook;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Facebook {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        WebElement email= driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Actions seriesOfActions = builder.moveToElement(email).click().sendKeys(email, "gati.naveen@gmail.com");
        seriesOfActions.perform();
        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        WebElement login =driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b"));
        Actions seriesOfAction = builder.moveToElement(pass).click().sendKeys(pass, "naveench").click(login);
        seriesOfAction.perform();
        driver.
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 18):

This is simple if you only use Selenium WebDriver, and forget the usage of Selenium-RC. I'd go like this.

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
email.sendKeys("your@email.here");
```

The reason for `NullPointerException` however is that your variable `driver` has never been started, you start `FirefoxDriver` in a variable `wb` thas is never being used.

Comment: i am new on selenium and learning form web. can you customize me code?

Comment: I could, but that's not the point of learning. The answer is right there, all you need to do is imply that in your code. Also i would (once again) advise you to drop SeleniumRC, as it's outdated.

Comment: If someone disagrees with me, feel free to edit my code and suit the user needs.

Comment: Now i edit my code according to you but it still not working.

Comment: Are you still getting NullPointerException? Which line?

Comment: thanks Aimbire, you give a way to solve my problem. i resolved this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should replace `WebDriver wb = new FirefoxDriver();` with `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` in your `@Before` Annotation.

As you are accessing `driver` object with null or you can make `wb` reference variable as global variable.

Comment: Thanks Omkar i resolved this problem. if you like me answer please upvote this.

Comment: i can upvote your answer. It did not resolved my entire problem so, i did not accept it sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("emal@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this using xpath

```
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//*[@id='email'])).sendKeys("your@email.here");
```

Hope that will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript as well, in case the textfield is dithered.

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost/login.do");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
RemoteWebDriver r=(RemoteWebDriver) driver;
String s1="document.getElementById('username').value='admin'";
r.executeScript(s1);
```