# Unable to type in a textfield using sendkeys in both selenium WebDriver and appium in an android app

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

..I have tried different solutions given on stackoverflow such as [How to type in textbox using Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2) with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481418/how-to-type-in-textbox-using-selenium-webdriver-selenium-2-with-java)
 but still unable to enter the text.
click() function is not working as the default text remains and new text is not entered..Below is my code:

```
    public boolean setConfiguration(WebDriver driver)   
    {       
    String server_url="http://qe.digite.com:6680/digite";   
    try         
    {                   
    WebElement URL=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='URL']")));          
    URL.click();        
    URL.clear();    
    URL.sendKeys(server_url);               
    System.out.println("URL entered");      
    return true;
    }   

    catch(Exception e)      
    {                   
System.out.println("Element not found");            
Assert.fail("Configuration failed");            
return false;       
    }   
}
```

Also I have tried the JavascriptExecutor and action class..but still no luck..The URL textfield in which text is to be entered is not in any iframe as well..when i run the above code, the field is getting clicked but the text is not being entered. kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: what happens if you comment out URL.clear() and directly enter the value of url like URL.sendkeys("http://qe.digite.com:6680/digite");

Comment: the element gets selected but no text is entered

Comment: what does URL.getText() results?(put it in system.out....)

Comment: give some sleep time after click and clear and try

Comment: URL.getText() is not returning any value..

Comment: I gave sleep time as given below: 
URL.click();        
    URL.clear();    
Thread.sleep(20000);     
    URL.sendKeys(server_url);     Still not working

Comment: can you please provide the HTML code of that text box?

Comment: The HTML for the URL field is :  <input type="text" class="url" name="url" placeholder="URL" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none">